# Prevent Ambari agent overwriting repo files

Tags: hadoop, proxy, ambari

I am installing HDP components behind corporate firewall which need internet proxy for only hortonworks components while some of dependencies are available in private cloud. So need to set proxy specific to repos inside *.repo files. Installation through ambari agent overwrites repo files. Is there a config that I can specify in ambari-agent.ini to stop agent from overwriting repo file

```
 2017-01-08 12:22:14,039 - Writing File['/etc/yum.repos.d/HDP.repo'] because contents don't match
    2017-01-08 12:22:14,040 - Repository['HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21'] {'base_url': 'http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21/repos/centos7', 'action': ['create'], 'components': [u'HDP-UTILS', 'main'], 'repo_template': '[{{repo_id}}]\nname={{repo_id}}\n{% if mirror_list %}mirrorlist={{mirror_list}}{% else %}baseurl={{base_url}}{% endif %}\n\npath=/\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=0', 'repo_file_name': 'HDP-UTILS', 'mirror_list': None}
    2017-01-08 12:22:14,043 - File['/etc/yum.repos.d/HDP-UTILS.repo'] {'content': '[HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21]\nname=HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21\nbaseurl=http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21/repos/centos7\n\npath=/\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=0'}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into exactly the same problem and solved it setting up nginx to proxy connections to the hortonworks server and then updated the Ambari configurations to point to the proxy server for the HDP and HDP-UTILS repo configurations.

So, assuming that you are using nginx and that you can access it on your local/Hadoop network via `http://myproxy:8888`, add the following configuration block in your nginx.conf

```
location ~* /(ambari|HDP) {
    proxy_pass http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com;
}
```

Then restart nginx.

Then, going through the Ambari web console, go to `admin/Manage Ambari/`

Then under `Clusters` click on `Versions`

Then, click on the version of HDP that you have installed and for your OS version update the HDP and HDP-UTILS url to point to your proxy server as follows changing:

```
http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos7/2.x/updates/2.3.4.7
```

to

```
http://myproxy:8888/HDP/centos7/2.x/updates/2.3.4.7
```

Make sure that you do NOT skip the repo base URL validation and when you click the Save button it will attempt to connect to the repo through your proxy.  If you do not see any errors you should be good to go.

If you do see any errors check your proxy configs/logs.

Comment: I think its great solution, considering if you have access to such internal server with full internet access. I am wondering if we can have similar solution to redirect the traffic if the nginx is also installed in a server with internet access only via proxy?